# gnuplot: solid filled triangle in 3D - splot function

Tags: gnuplot

I have this file (x.txt):

```
0 0 0
0 0 2
2 2 1
0 0 0
```

which has coordinates of vertexes that should make the triangle.

I want the triangle to be filled. I tried few ways, but didn't succeed:

```
splot "x.txt" with lines     #triangle is not filled

splot "x.txt" with pm3d      #I can see only points

set style fill solid
splot "x.txt" with lines     #Just lines
```

I saw few examples on the internet showing how to do it, but none of them worked for my points. Example: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/hidden2.html - almost what I want. I want the color not to change and be the same on the whole surface of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only this one triangle, you must change your file a bit and use `set pm3d ftriangles`. Usually, this is used to draw a smooth boundary if two subsequent scans don't have the same number of points:

File `x.txt`:

```
0 0 0

0 0 2
2 2 1
```

Plot it with

```
set pm3d ftriangles
splot 'x.txt' w pm3d notitle
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]